# While using the IntentIntegrator from the ZXing library, can I add a flash button to the barcode scanner via the Intent?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am scanning barcodes and QR codes from an Android app via Intent using the [ZXing Library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and [its port of the Android Application](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded). I added the following two lines in my Gradle dependencies to use the android-integration code without modification:

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

And I am using [`IntentIntegrator`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) in my Activity to scan a barcode in the `onCreate()`  like this:

```
integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
integrator.setPrompt(getString(R.string.scanner_text)); // Set the text of the scanner
integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
integrator.setBeepEnabled(true); // Enable beep in the scanner
integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false); // Do not fetch image from the camera
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Everything works and I get correct scanned result, but I want a flash button in the lower right corner of the scanner like this:

[image]

I can already control the flash using the volume up and down keys because I override the [`CaptureActivity`](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/journeyapps/barcodescanner/CaptureActivity.java).
Is a flash button like the one above already there in the barcode scanner which can switch between AUTO, ON and OFF mode? If there is, can I use the `addExtra()` method of the `IntentIntegrator` to activate it? Or is the only way to implement this would be to modify the entire code according to my needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had overlooked [this page on Embedding BarcodeView](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/EMBEDDING.md) and [these sample activities](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing) which show how to customise the Barcode Scanner according to your needs. The example activity that helped me was [`CustomScannerActivity`](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/CustomScannerActivity.java).

There isn't a option in the [`IntentIntegrator`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) class to implement a flash button natively. Instead I should make a custom layout for the Barcode Scanner, use it in a custom activity and call this activity from the `IntentIntegrator`.

I have two activities. One is the `ScannerActivity` and other one is the `CallingActivity`. A mistake that confused me for a while was that I created an instance of `IntentIntegrator` in the `onCreate()` method of `ScannerActivity`. It should be in the `CallingActivity`.

In the example given a `Button` is used and the text of the `Button` is changed according to the flash. I created a new Android Layout called `activity_custom_scanner` where I replaced the Button with a ToggleButton and used images for the button instead to get my desired Flash On/Off Button.

So my ScannerActivity looks like this:

```
public class CustomScannerActivity extends Activity implements
        CompoundBarcodeView.TorchListener {

    private static final int BarCodeScannerViewControllerUserCanceledErrorCode = 99991;

    private static final String TAG = CustomScannerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private CaptureManager capture;
    private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;
    private ToggleButton switchFlashlightButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_scanner);

        barcodeScannerView = (CompoundBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
        barcodeScannerView.setTorchListener(this);

        switchFlashlightButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.switch_flashlight);

        switchFlashlightButton.setText(null);
        switchFlashlightButton.setTextOn(null);
        switchFlashlightButton.setTextOff(null);

        // if the device does not have flashlight in its camera,
        // then remove the switch flashlight button...
        if (!hasFlash()) {
            switchFlashlightButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        switchFlashlightButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // Save the state here
                if (isChecked) {
                    barcodeScannerView.setTorchOn();
                } else {
                    barcodeScannerView.setTorchOff();
                }
            }
        });

        capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
        capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
        capture.decode();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        capture.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        capture.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        capture.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return barcodeScannerView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    /**
     * Check if the device's camera has a Flashlight.
     * @return true if there is Flashlight, otherwise false.
     */
    private boolean hasFlash() {
        return getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTorchOn() {
        // necessary override..
    }


    @Override
    public void onTorchOff() {
        // necessary override..
    }

}
```

And the `CallingActivity` looks like this:

```
public class CallingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = CallingActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int BarCodeScannerViewControllerUserCanceledErrorCode = 99991;

    String uuid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uuid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uuid");
        new IntentIntegrator(this).setOrientationLocked(false).setCaptureActivity(CustomScannerActivity.class).initiateScan();
    }



    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (scanResult != null) {

                // handle scan result
                Log.i(TAG, "Text from Barcode Scanner: " + scanResult.getContents());
                getIntent().putExtra("data", scanResult.getContents());
                getIntent().putExtra("uuid", uuid);
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            getIntent().putExtra("error", "User canceled");
            getIntent().putExtra("error_code", BarCodeScannerViewControllerUserCanceledErrorCode);
        }
        else
        {
            getIntent().putExtra("error", getString(R.string.scanner_error));
            getIntent().putExtra("error_code", BarCodeScannerViewControllerUserCanceledErrorCode);
        }

        setResult(resultCode, this.getIntent());

        this.finish();
    }

}
```

I am not sure if it's the perfect way, but that's how I did it.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

There is a setTorchOn method in CompoundBarcodeView so you can check that method out and try to implement it for your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did figure it out and I am implementing the `CompoundBarcodeView` class to make a `CustomScannerActivity`. Writing an answer to explain shortly what I did.

Comment: Where is this CompoundBarcodeView-class you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably too old, but you can use the Volume buttons to turn on/off the torch while scanning.

Comment: How will normal user know volume up will turn on the camera :D